# facebook create app for page to upload photos to page's photo album

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm completely new to Facebook app development, so please bear with me.

I've been asked to create a Facebook Page, with an application that will let users upload photos into one of the Page's albums.

I've managed to create the page, let's call it `MyPage`. I've also created an app `MyApp`, and I've added the App to the profile of the Page. Now, when you view `MyPage` profile, on the left (tabs), you will already find `MyApp`.

`MyApp` points to a php page on my hosting account. It has a form with a file field:

```
<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF;?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" type="hidden" value="10000000" />
    <input id="fileSelect" name="fileSelect" type="file" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

and the following code to handle the uploaded file and supposedly put into `MyPage`'s album:

```
if(count($_FILES)){
    $name = ereg_replace(' ', '_', basename($_FILES['fileSelect']['name'])); 
    $uploadFile = "uploads/" . $name; 
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileSelect']['tmp_name'], $uploadFile)) { 
    $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

    $args = array('message' => 'Photo Caption');
    $args['image'] = '@' . realpath($uploadFile);

    $data = $facebook->api('/THE_ALBUM_ID/photos', 'post', $args);

    //get rid of the original on the main server 
    unlink($uploadFile);
    }
}
```

However, when the "Upload" button is submitted, I get this error, right in `MyPage`'s iframe for `MyApp`:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#120) Invalid album id thrown in /COMPLETE_PATH/facebook-php-sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1033
```

Even tho the album id is really correct, and displays when I use Graph API Explorer, or `graph.facebook.com/THE_ALBUM_ID`

By the way, I put this on top of the script:

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'THE_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'THE_APP_SECRET',
));
```

What am I missing? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I found to upload photos to a page through the Facebook API is doing it AS the Page. In order to do that you need to authenticate as the page first. To do that you have to:

1. Authenticate with the user who owns the page with the `manage_pages` permission.
2. Request the pages with

   `/me/accounts?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`
3. Find the `access_token` of the corresponding page.
4. Use that `access_token` to upload photos.

If you need USERS to upload photos to the page you could get a long lived token with the user who owns the page and store it to use that token instead of users tokens to upload photos. The uploaded photo won't appear uploaded as the user though, it will appear uploaded by the page.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using CURL and hitting the graph api direct instead of using the SDK.  The below works for me.  I have a function that I pass in a variable called image which is an array of token,file(full path to file), and the album id and then use the following code.

```
$args = array( 
   'access_token' => $image['token'], 
   'message' => 'Photo Caption', 
   'no_story' => 1
);
$args['image'] = '@' . $image['file'];
$target_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$image['album_id']."/photos";

$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args);    
curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

You'll need to make sure you have the `manage_pages` and the `upload_photos` permissions granted to the token you pass into the call.

Comment: Wanted to clarify something in your solution. When you say "granted to the token you pass in" are you refering to the user's token visiting my app? Or would this be a token in the server-side with the page owner's credential?

Comment: Note: the permission should be `photo_upload` instead of `uploads_photos`.

Comment: the cURL method does not work. The photo is uploaded to user's photo album instead, though correct Album ID is selected & related permissions are granted. Plus, the token is generated by the page admin.